# what does auto number data format indicates

Tags: custom-object, administration, custom-field, record-type

In the below screen shot :

[image]

I would like to understand where does the data format for this record name is used?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_attributes.htm&language=en#Auto-NumberFormattingExamples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> what is the significance of this format?

The significance of the format is application-specific. For example, I worked on an org where we wanted all the quotes to go out with the business unit's abbreviation followed by a numerical sequence identifier

```
ACME-{000000}
```

The field you are formatting is the `Name` field, present on almost all Sobjects.  It is a field that is indexed and hence readily queryable

The field appears by default on all OOB standard page layouts in the section header. It also appears in the recent items list in the sidebar

I personally find it useful to make the prefix somehow tie to the Sobject name when there is no otherwise overriding business requirement such as in my quote example

For example, an auto number field on a custom `Line_Item__c` object might be formatted as `LI-{0000000}`

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new record, Salesforce will give that record a sequential Name. That sequence is simply a number that increments by 1 every time you get a new record.

However, Salesforce also recognizes that naming a record "1" makes little sense. Because of that, it allows you to give it a format so it displays a little nicer.

For example:

- A Format of `XX-{0}` = XX-1, XX-2, XX-3 and so on
- A Format of `XX-{000000}` = XX-000001, XX-000002, XX-000003 and so on

A nice side effect of adding all those zeros at the beginning is that then you can sort properly.

For Example:

- If you have XX-1, XX-2 and XX-10. The sort is XX-1, XX-10, XX-2.
- However, If you have XX-001, XX-002 and XX-010. The sort is XX-001,
  XX-002, XX-010, which is the correct sort.

As sfdcfox suggested below, you can also use a few different types of formats. If your Format needs to include a time component (example: 2016-01 0001) you can use 
`{YY}`, `{YYYY}`, `{MM}`, or `{DD}`

You can find the complete documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_attributes.htm&language=en_US#Auto-NumberFormattingExamples) .

Comment: You could mention that you can use other merge values, too, like YYYY, MM, DD... https://login.salesforce.com/setup/ui/whatisdisplayformat.jsp

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I just updated my post

Comment: Thanks guys. Can you guys let me know , what is the significance of this format. I mean where can it be used. for example the records are identified by 15 dgit id and we can use that id anywhere in apex class or soql,sosl to identify the record. Similarly is there any use of this record name format?

Comment: Hi, that field acts just like any other field. It is called "Name" and its contents are text, so yes, you can soql them. The main differentiation is that, normally, that field is the one that has a link on it (when shown on a page or related list) and the one you can search for by default when the object is the parent in a parent-child relationship.